# Put the numbers $1, 2, ...,16$ in circles

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

[image]

Put the numbers $1, 2, 3, ..., 16$ in circles so that the sum of the four numbers on each side of the triangle should be equal.

Comment: Did you create this puzzle or did you find it somewhere? If you did not create it, please add a citation to where you found it

Comment: @lioness99a, i found a paper with the sketch only, I tried the find the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution (probably many more of them exist):

> (Sorry for the image quality)
>  Here, all 6 sides of 2 large triangles give the sum of **34**.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Definitely many more exist - e.g. from your solution there's no restriction on swapping 8 and 9, 12 and 16, 1 and 14.
In addition 6 can be swapped with 11 and 2 with 15 if the corresponding pairs of circles above them are also swapped left-to-right.
Those swaps could be done on ANY valid solution, so any others will spawn at least 2^5 = 32 "equivalent" solutions from swapping.

Comment: How you find the 34? I found the sum of given numbers, it is 136, then 136 : 4 = 34. What is 4 here?

Comment: Not only "many" more solutions, but many thousands of them... ignoring the "no-computers" tag (so won't submit an answer), I found a total of 27086 unique solutions, each of which corresponds to one of a set of 32 solutions that can be generated by swapping some of the circles. Totals along sides of the triangles can be anything from 30 to 38.

Comment: @Nick 4 of the 16 numbers are totalled for each of the sides. To explain how totals other than 34 are possible - note that 8 of the circles are included in 2 totals, and 8 are included only in 1 total.

Comment: @Steve, could you share your alternative solution?

Comment: @Nick Since the sum of all numbers 136 is 4 modulo 6, the sum of the 8 numbers which belong to 2 different sides must be 2 modulo 6 (we need A+B=136 and A+2B divisible by 6, where A is sum of the 8 numbers belonging to 1 side only, and B is sum of 8 others). Since 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36 and 16+15+14+13+12+11+10+9=100, B can range from 38 to 98, so A+2B can be from 174 to 234, and the sum must be 29 to 39 (it's an open question if the bound are in fact reachable).

Comment: Also note - a solution with total 30 can be converted to one with total 38 and vice-versa etc. by swapping each number (N) with the number (17-N). @trolley813 : 30 and 38 are reachable (I get 426 * 32 solutions for each), 29 and 39 are not. Nick: I have a total of 27086 * 32 solutions available. I don't think it's fair on those honouring the no-computers tag to share them.