# Is it possible to put the numbers into circles?

Tags: mathematics, puzzle-creation

This topic is motivated by the [trolley813's  answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21511/trolley813) on my [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92837/put-the-numbers-1-2-16-in-circles).

[image]

**Question.** Is it possible to put the numbers $1,2,3,...,23$ in circles so that the sum of the four numbers on $9$ sides of $3$ large triangles give the same sum?

Edit. All numbers should be used one time.

**My attempt is:**

The total sum is $1+2+...+23=276$, but $13$ numbers (yellow and blue circles) are totalled for each of the sides twice.

The possible sum of $4$ numbers in each side is $276 : 4 = 69$, if one takes the minimal number $1$  and add three maximal numbers $21, 22, 23$, then $1 + 21 + 22 + 23 = 67 < 69$.

Also it is known that $276 \mod 9 = 6$. Now I do not know is it possible to decrease the sum of $4$ numbers on each side from $69$?

Comment: I've ran a computer search and found many solutions for sides that sum to $44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52$, so far.

Comment: What are up and down boundary of sum?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've ran a simple brute force search for some of the possible combinations only. There could still be solutions with $\lt 44$ and $\gt 52$ sums.

Comment: The upper and lower bounds are 42 and 54 respectively, as shown in both my and Michał Wójcik's answers. The only remaining part is if solution with 43 and 53 do actually exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with minimal side-sum:

> [image]
>  **side sum = 42**

This was found by brute-force.

The code below will traverse between the bounds as identified by trolley813 and prints a solution with each side-sum (42 & 54 take a while but the rest are much faster). The output solutions are in row-major order.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def iterSolutions(sideSum):
    Q = set(list(range(1, 24)))
    for A in combinations(range(1, 24), 4):
        if sum(A) != sideSum:
            continue
        Q1 = Q.difference(A)
        for a, d, b, c in list(permutations(A))[::2]:
            for B in combinations(Q1, 3):
                if a + sum(B) != sideSum:
                    continue
                Q2 = Q1.difference(B)
                for g, e, f in list(permutations(B))[::3]:
                    for h, i in combinations(Q2, 2):
                        if d + h + i + g != sideSum:
                            continue
                        Q3 = Q2.difference((h, i))
                        for D in combinations(Q3, 3):
                            if h + sum(D) != sideSum:
                                continue
                            Q4 = Q3.difference(D)
                            for j, k, l in permutations(D):
                                for E in combinations(Q4, 2):
                                    if j + i + sum(E) != sideSum:
                                        continue
                                    Q5 = Q4.difference(E)
                                    for m, n in permutations(E):
                                        for o, p in combinations(Q5, 2):
                                            if l + o + p + n != sideSum:
                                                continue
                                            Q6 = Q5.difference((o, p))
                                            for G in combinations(Q6, 3):
                                                if o + sum(G) != sideSum:
                                                    continue
                                                Q7 = Q6.difference(G)
                                                for q, r, s in permutations(G):
                                                    for H in combinations(Q7, 2):
                                                        if q + p + sum(H) != sideSum:
                                                            continue
                                                        v, w = Q7.difference(H)
                                                        for t, u in permutations(H):
                                                            if s + v + w + u == sideSum:
                                                                yield (a, b, e, c, j, f, d, h, i, g, k, q, m, l, o, p, n, r, t, s, v, w, u)


def main():
    lowerBound = 42
    upperBound = 54
    for sideSum in range(lowerBound, upperBound + 1):
        print(sideSum)
        for solution in iterSolutions(sideSum):
            print(solution)
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results:

> ```
> 42
> (1, 15, 12, 23, 4, 22, 3, 13, 19, 7, 17, 5, 10, 8, 11, 14, 9, 20, 21, 6, 16, 18, 2)
> 43
> (1, 17, 18, 23, 4, 21, 2, 16, 22, 3, 9, 8, 11, 14, 10, 13, 6, 20, 15, 5, 19, 12, 7)
> 44
> (1, 18, 19, 23, 4, 21, 2, 17, 22, 3, 7, 6, 13, 16, 8, 15, 5, 20, 12, 10, 9, 14, 11)
> 45
> (1, 19, 20, 23, 4, 21, 2, 18, 22, 3, 6, 10, 14, 17, 7, 16, 5, 15, 8, 13, 9, 12, 11)
> 46
> (1, 20, 22, 23, 3, 4, 2, 7, 18, 19, 15, 14, 17, 21, 6, 11, 8, 10, 9, 16, 5, 13, 12)
> 47
> (1, 21, 22, 23, 7, 4, 2, 6, 19, 20, 18, 17, 9, 16, 5, 14, 12, 10, 3, 15, 8, 11, 13)
> 48
> (1, 22, 21, 23, 17, 6, 2, 7, 19, 20, 8, 14, 3, 16, 11, 12, 9, 13, 4, 10, 5, 15, 18)
> 49
> (1, 22, 21, 23, 19, 7, 3, 8, 18, 20, 9, 16, 2, 13, 11, 15, 10, 5, 4, 17, 6, 12, 14)
> 50
> (1, 4, 21, 23, 20, 11, 22, 5, 6, 17, 12, 16, 9, 13, 8, 14, 15, 7, 2, 19, 3, 10, 18)
> 51
> (5, 1, 16, 23, 21, 19, 22, 8, 10, 11, 7, 18, 6, 15, 9, 13, 14, 4, 3, 20, 2, 12, 17)
> 52
> (22, 6, 17, 23, 13, 2, 1, 19, 21, 11, 4, 15, 8, 16, 12, 14, 10, 7, 3, 18, 5, 9, 20)
> 53
> (22, 1, 14, 23, 19, 4, 7, 12, 21, 13, 5, 16, 3, 17, 11, 15, 10, 8, 2, 18, 6, 9, 20)
> 54
> (23, 1, 17, 9, 22, 2, 21, 6, 15, 12, 10, 18, 3, 16, 11, 13, 14, 5, 4, 20, 7, 8, 19)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer since it had an error in computation, actual lower and upper bounds are 42 and 54 respectively (if you swap 1 with 23, 2 with 22, 3 with 21 etc. in your solution, then you can get a solution with sum = 54).

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer based on both my own's answer to the original question and Steve's comments on it:

> Let $W$ be sum of the 10 white numbers, and $C$ the sum of 13 coloured numbers (blue and yellow). We know that $W+C=276$ and $W+2C=9S$, where $S$ is the sum of one side. But since the 2 sides completely consist of coloured numbers, we can safely say that $C\geqslant2S+15$ (since the 5 remaining blue numbers cannot be less than $1,2,3,4,5$, which sum to 15). So, we get
>  $$9S=W+2C=276+C\geqslant276+2S+15=2S+291 \rightarrow 7S\geqslant291 \rightarrow S\geqslant42$$.
>  By noticing that replacing each number $x$ with $24-x$ (in a valid solution) also leads to a valid solution, we have $S$ replaced with $96-S$. Since necessarily $96-S\geqslant42$, we get $S\leqslant54$ (fixed an error: initially the bounds were 43 and 53 respectively, due to the error in computation - literally dividing 291 by 7)

Comment: Not me actually! Try [@Steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12582/steve)...

Comment: @Stiv Oh, sorry! Fixing

Comment: @trolley813, your partial answer is analytical. Could you add some details/conditions how to decrease the number of combinations and permutations?

Answer (score 2):

With branch-and-bound algorithm wrote in Python, I found couple of solutions with the highest possible sum of side (inspired with [trolley813's partial answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/92869/64484)). One of them is here:

> [image: A solution]
>
>  Accually, the maximum edge sum is **54** because:
>
>  $$9S=W+2C=276+C\leqslant276+2S+105=2S+381 \rightarrow 7S\leqslant381 \rightarrow S\leqslant54.43$$.
>
>   Due to fact that the maximum sum of the remaining 5 blue circles is:
>
>   $$19+20+21+22+23=105$$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: bubbles]

The numbers in the circles on the long sides of the three triangles all add up to 43.

Comment: How you find the 43?

Comment: @Nick. I did it with combinatorics, permutations and by grouping the numbers.

Comment: Could you please share your solution idea?

Comment: @Νick. If you add the numbers from 1 to 23 then you get the sum of 276.  If you divide this number by 3 you have 92. If you take the middle value of 92 then you have 46 and the nearest primes to that number are 43 and 47. By grouping and combinations I chose 43.

Comment: You've used 7 twice (bottom right blue, lower left yellow) (and there are two 3's and 13's with no 6,16,21).

Comment: @Jim I didn't know that repetitions are not allowed and all numbers have to be used.

Comment: You could have used all 1's!